# Python any() function on nested list returning incorrect value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello I am trying to use the any() function in python. From reading the documentation the function should return True anytime there is a True in the list. However in my nested list below the function is returning true despite being no True values in the list.

```
b = [[False, False], [False, False]]
print(any(b))
```

prints
`True`

I am trying to return False if all values in list are False and True if any value is True so negating it won't work. How do I fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `bool([False])` is True. It's a non-empty list

Comment: There are two values in your list. You have two nested lists, hence the return of `True`, if you iterate and call `any()` on each element, you will get `False`

Answer (score 3):

How about doing

```
any(any(x) for x in b)
```

this would check each list in the list for True and then check if any of those results were True

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are only dealing with one level of nesting, you could simply `map` `any()` onto the list items and take `any()` of that:

```
b = [[False, False], [False, False]]
any(map(any, b))
# False

c = [[False, False], [False, True]]
any(map(any,c))
# True
```

Of course, if your items can be nested arbitrarily you need a couple more lines of code.

```
b = [[False, False], False, [False, [False, True]]]
c = [[False, False], False, [False, [False, False]]]

def any_nested(item):
     if not isinstance(item, list):
        return bool(item)
     return any(map(any_nested, item))

any_nested(b)
# True
any_nested(c)
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to flatten the nested list. If you pass that to `any`, you will get the result you want. This will work for any level of nesting, not just two.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> b = [[False, False], [False, False]]
>>> any(chain.from_iterable(b))
False
>>> c = [[False, False], [False, True]]
>>> any(chain.from_iterable(c))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

> The any() function returns true if any of the element in the passed list is true

In your case, you have two nested lists, and you're calling `any()` on the primary list. Technically, your primary list is `True`, as it contains two lists that have elements.

```
# Empty list returns False as no elements exist   
bool([])
False
# List with one element returns True
bool([0])
True
# Even with the list containing False, the list is `True` because it contains an element.
bool([False])
True
```

`any()` accepts an iterable, and checks if any value within said iterable, is `True` or `False`.

You're passing two lists with an element in each, resulting in a return of `True`, with your code you never actually check if the values in your nested lists, are `True` or `False`

```
bool([False, False])
True
```

If you iterate over the contents of the nested lists, you will get a return of `False`

```
for item in b:
    any(item)


False
False
```